# How do I save this nested form in Rails 4 with a has many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

The problem that I have here is that I have a nested form that won't save to the database and I'm suspecting it's because the proper attributes aren't being passed into the form prior to being saved.  Right now I'm trying to pass these values through hidden fields but I'm thinking there's probably a more "Railsy" way to do this.  This is the form that I have created to do this:

```
<%= form_for @topic do |f| %>

    <%= render "shared/error_messages", object: f.object %>

    <%= f.fields_for :subject do |s| %>

        <%= s.label :name, "Subject" %>
        <%= collection_select :subject, :id, Subject.all, :id, :name, {prompt:"Select a subject"} %>

    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :name, "Topic" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit class: "button radius" %></div>

<% end %>
```

This form generates a params hash that looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PdxVyZa3X7Sc6mjjQy1at/Ri7NpR4IPUzW09Fs8I710=", "subject"=>{"id"=>"5"}, "topic"=>{"name"=>"Ruby"}, "commit"=>"Create Topic", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"topics"}
```

This my model for `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics
    has_many :subjects, through: :topics
end
```

In my `subject.rb` file:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics
    has_many :users, through: :topics, dependent: :destroy
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

In my `topic.rb` file:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subject
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subject
    validates :name, presence: true
end

class TopicsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login

    def new
        @topic = Topic.new
        @topic.build_subject
    end

    def create
        @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
        @topic.user_id = current_user.id
        @topic.subject_id = params[:subject][:id]
        if @topic.save
            flash[:success] = "Success!"
            render :new
        else
            flash[:error] = "Error!"
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
    def topic_params
        params.require(:topic).permit(:name,:subject_id,:user_id, subjects_attributes: [:name])
    end
end
```

So I'm getting closer to having a successful form submission!  I placed the method `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the join model, which in this case is in `topic.rb`.  I don't really know why this works but I'm thinking it allows Rails to properly set the ":user_id" and ":subject_id" compared to placing `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on a model containing the "has_many through" relationship.  I saw it on this post btw: http://makandracards.com/makandra/1346-popular-mistakes-when-using-nested-forms

NOW, I still have a problem where the ":subject_id" isn't being properly saved into the database.  Would I have to pass in a hidden field to do this or would I have to do something else like nest my routes?

Comment: Can you explain this line '@subject.topics.build'? Sorry I'm pretty new to Rails 4.

Comment: what happens if you remove `<%= t.hidden_field :subject_id, value: params[:topic] %>`.  That line should be handled by `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  setting the value of `subject_id` to `params[:topic]` also looks wrong.

Comment: @Pavan That line just creates a new instance of a topic through the association and routes that I wrote

Comment: @jvnill Do you think you could look at my revisions and how I could pass in the ":subject_id" so it gets saved into the database?

Comment: You don't need the `fields_for` for the subject.  A simple `f.collection_select :subject_id, Subject.all, :id, :name, {prompt:"Select a subject"}` should work.

Comment: @jvnill Thanks for your help but I figured out the problem myself!

Answer (score 1):

Wow that took forever to figure this one out.  Since I have a has_many through relationship and I'm trying to created a nested form involving one of these models the problem I was having was I was placing the "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in the wrong model I was placing it in the has_many through model in the `subject.rb` file when it should have been placed in the model responsible for the join between two tables.

Also I made a super idiotic mistake on this line when I was trying to save the ":subject_id".  I was writing this: `@topic.subject_id = params[:subject_id][:id]` instead of something like this:

```
@topic.subject_id = params[:subject][:id]
```

It was a really dumb mistake (probably because I was copying a pasting code from another controller haha)

Anyways I hope others can learn from my mistake if they ever want to do a nested form on models with a "has_many through" relationship, in certain cases the "accepts_nested_attributes_for" method will go on the JOIN table and NOT on the model with the "has_many through" relationship